# Brewing up custom ML models on AWS SageMaker

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

Iam new with SageMaker and I try to use my own sickit-learn algorithm . For this I use Docker.
I try to do the same task as described here in this github account : https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/advanced_functionality/scikit_bring_your_own/scikit_bring_your_own.ipynb

My question is should I create manually the repository **`/opt/ml`**  (I work with windows OS) ?

Can you explain me please?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to create `/opt/ml`, SageMaker will do it for you when it launches your training job.

The contents of the `/opt/ml` directory are determined by the parameters you pass to the CreateTrainingJob API call. The scikit example notebook you linked to describes this (look at the **Running your container** sections). You can find more info about this in the [Create a Training Job](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/ex1-train-model-create-training-job.html) section of the main SageMaker documentation.

---